# C++ initializing an array with size from standard input

Tags: c++, arrays

When I need to store multiple values of same type in c++ I can use a vector or array. So far I have mainly only used vectors, but I have heard that arrays are faster to work with (read and write values). If this is true I would like to know how I could make an array with the size that I read from standard input. I currently use something like this:

```
int N;
cin >> N;
vector<int> myVector(N);
```

I have tried:

```
int N;
cin >> N;
array<int, N> myArray;
```

but this gives me an error because:
error: the value of 'N' is not usable in a constant expression
I have also tried:

```
int N;
cin >> N;
int myArray[N];
```

This will compile, but when I try to ask for the size of this array (`myArray.size()`) to iterate over it with a for loop then I get an error:
error: request for member 'size' in 'myArray', which is of non-class type 'int [N]'

**So should I replace vectors with arrays to make my code faster and if so the how should I do it?**

Comment: ***should I replace vectors with arrays to make my code faster*** No you need a dynamic array so use a vector.

Comment: `std::array`’s speed advantage (and its size limitation for stack-based objects) come from the fact that `std::array`s size is known at compile-time and it can, thus, avoid allocation and, more importantly, an indirection. There may be a place for an `std::array`-like data structure which has a known upper size but a dynamic size up to this upper likit. However, there is no such data structure in the standard C++ library.

Comment: `int myArray[N];` is a VLA. This is not legal c++ but a compiler extension. I doubt it is any faster than vector anyways and it makes your code only work on compilers that support this non standard extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`N` should be known at compile time. So, if you want to use `array` for I/O operations you should specify maximum number of `int`s that is allowed to read. Also, you should track number of read integers on your own.

> So should I replace vectors with arrays to make my code faster and if
>   so the how should I do it?

No, because `operator>>` would be the bottleneck in your case. And working with `vector` when number of `int`s  is not known is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

an array is not an object in c++ so there is no .size() function. You should instead have another variable holding it's size.

```
int* array = new int[size];
```

it's the way. But you should have solid reasons to do this as vector it's much more safer and easer to use.

after using the array you must delete it:

```
delete [] array;
```

and remember you can always get an array from a vector just by using the vector::data() function

Comment: Everything else is good... but I downvoted for the last point, which is dangerously false. Does that even compile? It shouldn't, because that's not a valid implicit cast. Anyway, `std::vector` does not provide an overridden `operator&` that would access its buffer, and nor should it. If such code *happened* to work on your compiler, then (A) I have no idea how and (B) you need to replace that code immediately, because it shouldn't work and may blow up horribly at any moment.

Comment: @underscore_d I think he meant the `vector::data()` function. That would be, indeed, a pointer to the underlying data array.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data

Comment: Right, and -1 removed. Of course, that underlying array is managed by the `vector`, so we can't substitute it into all cases where a raw array would be used, especially if they might try to `delete` it. I think it's best only to use `.data()` for passing to APIs that expect a raw pointer, and preferably a `const` one that they only read. Anything else is kind of asking for trouble and somewhat defeating the point of using `vector`. Still, there are cases where it can be convenient to use `.data()` and write, but I think they're best confined to whoever creates the `vector` & maintains its size

Comment: Arrays are objects in C++. You probably meant to say they are not classes and so can't have member functions.